# convolution inequality on R

Tags: analysis, integration, inequality, representation-theory

Let $\nu$ be a complex Radon measure on $\mathbb{R}$ such that 
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}} \check{\overline{f}}*f\ d\nu\geq 0
$$
for any complex continuous function $f$ with compact support, where $\check{f}(x)=f(-x)$ and where $*$ denote the convolution product.

Let $g$ be a continuous function with compact support on $\mathbb{R}$.

PROBLEM: Prove that there exists a positive constant $K_g$ such that 
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}} \check{\overline{g*f}}*(g*f)\ d\nu\leq K_g\int_{\mathbb{R}} \check{\overline{f}}*f \ d\nu
$$
for any continuous function $f$ with compact support on $\mathbb{R}$.

ps: I know that the result is true by using abstract representation theory but I does not see an elementary proof. Indeed, in "Treatise of Analysis 6" of Dieudonné, in 22.2.4, the author show this fact implicitely but does not give a direct argument.